# How do can I add a new format option to Moment.js locales?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to be able to format a date as the day and the shortened month. (ex: 20 Sep for en-gb, Sep 20 for en). However, the closest localized format that Moment.js has us the format 'll' which is Sep 20, 2017 for en. I want to be able to create a new format that excludes the year from 'll'. How can I best achieve this?

The end result I want (assuming today is Sept 20):

```
moment.locale('en');
moment().format('my-new-format')  ---> Sep 20
moment.locale('en-gb');
moment().format('my-new-format')  ---> 20 Sep
moment().format('ll')             ---> 20 Sep, 2017
```

Comment: Hope this helps (similar question) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028993/custom-long-date-format-in-moment-js

Comment: That's definitely a similar question! However, the answer isn't too helpful (aside from providing more evidence that maybe how I want to solve this problem isn't possible). I don't want to directly edit the libary or locale files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom long date format in moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028993/custom-long-date-format-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overwrite the localized by using the built in `updateLocale`

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        LT: "h:mm A",
        LTS: "h:mm:ss A",
        L: "MM/DD/YYYY",
        l: "M/D/YYYY",
        LL: "MMMM Do YYYY",
        ll: "MMM D YYYY",
        LLL: "MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        lll: "MMM D YYYY LT",
        LLLL: "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        llll: "ddd, MMM D YYYY LT"
    }
});
```

If you don't want to override the already existing locale, but still use it, I would go with a dictionary like this since adding new formats is not supported to my knowledge.

```
const formats = {
  en: "MMM D",
  sv: "DD MMM"
}
const customFormat() => formats[moment.locale()];
moment.locale("en");
console.log(moment().format(customFormat()));  // Jan 1
moment.locale("sv");
console.log(moment().format(customFormat())); // 01 Jan
```

Comment: please provide more of an answer then just a link, this is because if the link goes down this is no longer a helpful answer

Comment: LPL, I'm assuming you're pointing to updateLocale() but I don't think that will work for what I want (correct me if I'm wrong). I don't want to change 'll', I want to keep 'll' but add an entirely new format. It seems that updateLocale() only let's you change an existing format but doesn't let you add a new one.

Comment: Yes, I see, I don't think there is anything build in for that unfortunately. In that case I'd do it with a dictionary for my custom formats like `let custom = {en: "MM D", sv: "D MM"}` and then use the build in `moment.locale()` and solve it by `moment.format(custom[moment.locale()])`

Comment: @LPL that's the best way I've seen yet, can you edit your original answer so I can mark it as solved? Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

That seems to work with me... :

```
moment.updateLocale("en", { longDateFormat : { "[my-new-format]" : "MMM D" } });
moment.updateLocale("en-gb", { longDateFormat : { "[my-new-format]" : "DD MMM" } });
```

And then

```
moment.locale('en');
moment().format('[my-new-format]');
```

So you don't overwrite existing formats.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Importantly, it only works WITH the square brackets surrounding your custom format name, otherwise moment will attempt to interpret date-related characters within that name.