# How to get different formats of date using moment js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using moment js library for date formats. When i bugging the moment lib

```
moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L')
```

it returns the output format like this `MM/DD/YYYY` but  i need to return or display the date format like this `DD/MM/YYYY`. So what code changes i have to make to return this format?

I tried so many place i only getting answer like how to convert one date to other format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom long date format in moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028993/custom-long-date-format-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 1):

By default moment js return `MM/DD/YYYY` as format when using of `.longDateFormat('L')`. You should use [`.updateLocale()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) to changing it format.

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        L: "DD/MM/YYYY"
    }
});
```

As mentioned in [moment js docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/) you should change `L` property of `longDateFormat` object.

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        L: "DD/MM/YYYY"
    }
});
var long = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
console.log(long)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.js"></script>
```